# Access request headers of automatically loaded resources in CefSharp

Tags: c#, cookies, request, header, cefsharp

I am trying to use CefSharp to load a webpage and capture a cookie sent in request headers to the various resources it loads. I have been using Fiddler to capture the traffic, and when the main web page is loaded the cookie is not sent, but when various resources from the site are loaded, the cookie is sent. I'm trying to capture the headers sent while loading the resources so I can extract the cookies from them. I have seen something about implementing `IRequestHeader` in a similar question, but I couldn't quite figure out supposed to go about doing that. I'm trying to capture a cookie that looks like this:

`Cookie: cf_clearance=5cac41b8334ed94b9a36ff99a25dd95435553e2e-1608328601-0-150; __cfduid=d91983bcebf2963cde4a51ce71abf448c1608328601`

Comment: Do you need to access the headers or are you just interested in accessing cookies? You can access cookies independently

Comment: I need access to just the cookie, I'm not quite sure how cookies work and I thought that this was some cookie that was automatically deleted after it was used

Comment: You can access the cookie manager via http://cefsharp.github.io/api/86.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_GetGlobalCookieManager.htm see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/13e74fea8dcda826d602d1ee534b67f46e93bd15/CefSharp.Example/Handlers/BrowserProcessHandler.cs#L35 for some examples.